# Lack of access to create files in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, directory, operating-system, zip

In my application, I receive a folder as input with the file_picker package
And I turn it into a zip. But when I try to convert the folder to zip, I get this exption: '
FileSystemException (FileSystemException: Cannot create file, path = 'out.zip' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)) '
**Code Directory Picker:**

```
 _openDirectoryPicker() async{
String? path = await FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath();
if (path != null) {
  setState(() {
    ClientVariable.filePath = path;
  });
}
  }
```

**Code Create FileZip:**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:archive/archive_io.dart';
import 'package:send_data_with_wifi/variable/client.dart';

createZip() {
  var encoder = ZipFileEncoder();
  encoder.zipDirectory(Directory(ClientVariable.filePath), filename: 'out.zip');
  print(encoder.zipPath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application cannot write to `out.zip`.

Maybe you have an app and you don't have permissions on the device? Maybe you have a web app and cannot write outside the browser sandbox? Maybe the path on your computer is write protected? We don't know, you didn't say.

You need to pass not only a file name, but also a path where you have write permissions, so this file can be generated. What that path might be on your local device is something only you can figure out.